# Lock empty cells and unlock free cells

Tags: vba, excel

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcIVj.png)I am new to Excel and I am trying to write code that locks empty cells and unlocks the ones with values, any help will be highly appreciated. This is what I have and it is giving me

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range of object'_Global'failed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngTemp As Range

    For Each rngTemp In Range("grey").Cells
        With rngTemp
            If .Value > 0 Or Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                .Locked = False
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you must give to your rngTemp a range for example ("A1:X")

Comment: I changed the Range to Range("A1:B2").Cells and it took away the error but when I go to excel, nothing is locked. Is there another way you think I can write this? Sorry this is my first time and I am having a really hard time with it.

Comment: in order to lock a cell you must also protect your sheet with a password and only then you wont be able to write something in the empty cells from your Range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you have a range called "grey"?
[image: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you have a range called "grey"?]

Comment: Yes I have grey, Is there. I have the exact same thing you have but its giving me that range error. I am trying to post a screenshot of it but its not letting me in the comment box

Comment: Try to edit your question, I think you can attach a screenshot there.

Comment: Is there another way you think I can write this? Sorry this is my first time and I am having a really hard time with it.

Comment: It wasn't letting me attach to edit, so I attached it to the question. Control F Error Message and you should see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to set the range different way. For example:
    For Each rngTemp In Range("A1:B2").Cells
or
Dim wS As Worksheet
Set wS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet<br/>
For Each rngTemp In wS.Range(wS.PageSetup.PrintArea)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the Range to Range("A1:B2").Cells and it took away the error but when I go to excel, nothing is locked

Comment: If .Value > 0 Or Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                .Locked = False
            Else
                .Locked = True
            End If

Comment: I think it goes in an infinite loop because it says excel not responding after i try to run it. Does it work for you?