# How to dynamically lock and unlock a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

What should i do to dynamically lock/unlock my cell in excel? For example, if i create a new document, by default all cells are unlock but i entered a data on that cell it will be lock. I tried this, which i found here [Lock empty cells and unlock free cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511787/lock-empty-cells-and-unlock-free-cells)

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngTemp As Range

    For Each rngTemp In Range("A1:XFD1048576").Cells
        With rngTemp
            If .Value > 0 Or Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                .Locked = False
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

but it's not working on my case. I am using 2007 excel version. Do i still need to save the code or **Alt + Q** is enough?

---

**EDIT:** As per @JvdV's answer I tried the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
With Sheet1
    .Unprotect
    .Cells.Locked = True
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    .Protect
End With
End Sub
```

But this returns an error `Run-time error '1004' No cells were found` on `.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False`.

Comment: This code only unlocks non-empty cells, empty cells are not being locked. Also, this might take quite some time to run, depending on the size of your data.

Comment: I add ```.Locked = True``` on else statement but it's not still working.

Comment: I would recommend adding the worksheet you want to (un)lock in front of `Range("A1:XFD1048576")`, i.e. qualifiying the range. You can either use an index `Sheets(1)`, the name `Sheets("Sheet1")` (both not recommendend usually) or the object name `Sheet1` (recommended)

Comment: How? I mean, i am not very familiar with vba and this excel other than that the very basic.

Comment: Choose one of the ways I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: This looks like you looking to unlock all cells that are NOT empty. You can get that range in one go without any loop. Please confirm. Furthermore, indeed add a sheet's `CodeName` in front of your range to qualify it as per @M.Schalk.

Comment: Something like this ```Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1:XFD1048576").Cells```? I want that if i put a text on cell then it will automatically lock.

Comment: Like `Sheet1.Range("A1:XFD1048576").Cells`. As JvdV correctly said, you are ***unlocking*** cells that have values inside them. If you want cells to automatically (un)lock you will need to look into `Worksheet_Change` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really are intested in those cells, you can simply refer to a worksheet's cells. Also, no need to loop through those cells individually, for example:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's CodeName
    .Unprotect
    .Cells.Locked = False
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = True
    .Protect
End With

End Sub
```

Where `.Cells.Locked = False` unlocks all cells and `.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = True` locks all cells blank cells <sub>***(Note:*** a `=""` value through formulas is considered a value and will stay unlocked)</sub>

Both `Unprotect` and `Protect` are needed to have full effect of your changes.

If this is code you want to run each time a value is changed, you'll have to look into the `Worksheet_Change` event. And if your goal is to have empty cells unlocked and cells that contain a value locked, just swap around the `True` and `False`.

---

**EDIT** (as per your comments)

If this is something you like to run on every next selection of cells, try the following (error handler included since you not using the whole worksheet nomore)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet1.Unprotect 'Change according to your sheet's CodeName
With Target
    .Cells.Locked = True
    On Error Resume Next
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Sheet1.Protect

End Sub
```

If you looking for an alternative where you loop through your target range, you can implement the suggestion by @M.Schalk

Comment: In the case of locked cell, does it mean that it cannot be edited? I manually lock the cell but i am still able to edit it.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically unlock and unprotect a sheet if the current selected cell is null or empty in the code?

Comment: I tried your code and by switching the True and False but as i move to next cell vertically and horizontally it says ```The cell or chart you are trying to change is protected```. This is how i tweaks your code ```.Unprotect
    .Cells.Locked = True
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    .Protect```

Comment: I have updated my questions using the codes you give.

Comment: Do you mean ```Worksheet_SelectionChange```?

Comment: I got an error ```Run-time error '1004' No cells were found```

Comment: @AnirudhLou, I have edited my answer to cater for your comments. If this has helped, don't forget to upvote/accept any answer given to return the favor. Also, please clean up most of the comments above.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what i am looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically execute this code upon opening of an excel?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the (correct) answer above, here is my suggestion for a `Worksheet_Change` event, as you requested in the comments. This will have to be placed in the workbook-specific code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cll As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each cll In Target.Cells
    With cll
        If .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            .Locked = True
        Else
            .Locked = False
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

It's important to note, that (at least in my version of Excel) the `.Locked` property of a cell only has an effect when the sheet is protected. To change the value of the `.Locked` property however, the sheet must not be protected. To incorporate this you might want to use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cll As Range
On Error GoTo Handler

Me.Unprotect
For Each cll In Target.Cells
    With cll
        If .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            MsgBox cll.Value2
            .Locked = True
        Else
            MsgBox "NullString"
            .Locked = False
        End If
    End With
Next
Handler:
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

This will lead to every cell becoming un-changeable once a value is entered, while still letting the user enter values in all empty cells. To change existing values you will need to manually unprotect the sheet. You might use something like the code provided in the answer above to restore a desired state after the sheet was unprotected and changed.

Comment: I tried your code sir, but why i cannot enter a text on an empty cell? I pop up this message ```The cell or chart you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only```.

Comment: The cells are locked, and the sheet is protected. You will need to unprotect the sheet and then unlock the cells